# Pulling firestore image from firebase firestore database in react native - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to get an image from the firebase firestore database using react native, but I recieve the RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error, which I can not make out the purpose of. I have tried many solutions, none of which seemed to work for me. My code is below:

```
//Function being called:
  getPostImage = (post) => {
    return firebase.storage().ref(`photos/${post.uid}/${post.timestamp}.jpg`).getDownloadURL();
  };
...
//Calling the function in the image component:
<Image source={this.getPostImage(post)} style={styles.postImage} resizeMode="cover" />
```

Any help would be largely appreciated as I do not have any idea of what to do. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling method directly source you do like this :

first call async method and in between time display image with static image and when image will available display that.

```js
//Function being called:
getPostImage = async (post) => {
  const imageUrl = await firebase.storage().ref(`photos/${post.uid}/${post.timestamp}.jpg`).getDownloadURL();
  this.setState({
    downloadedImage: imageUrl
  });
};
...
//Calling the function in the image component:
<Image source={this.state.downloadedImage ? {uri: this.state.downloadedImage} : 'localPlaceholderImage.png'} style={styles.postImage} resizeMode="cover" />
```

Comment: Once I implement this code, I receive the warning that there is an invalid 'source' supplied to 'image'. How would I get around this? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Have you replaced `localImagePlaceholder.png` with your static image?

Comment: Yes, I have replaced the image with its correct url.

Comment: I managed to make the main error go away, but no image is now showing. I have no warnings but just blank spaces where images should be.

Comment: Actually, after building off of this code, this answer seems to work! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the API documentation, [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#get-downloadurl) is asynchronous and returns a promise that resolves with a URL, not a URL itself.  You will have to `await` it or use `then` to get its value.

Comment: I understand. Do you know how to implement this '.then()' statements as when I try to implement it onto the imageUrl, it sets the state to a recursive function.